# First order non linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(1+y)y' + (1-2x)y^2 = 0$$

I thought of using bernoulli equation but i cant bring it to the form

$$y' + P(x)y = F(x) y^n$$

**My attempt**
$$(1+y)y' + (1-2x)y^2 = 0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = (2x-1)\left(y-1 + \left(\frac{1}{y}+1\right)\right)$$

Should i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is separable.  Put all the $y$s on the left, and all the $x$s on the right, then integrate them separately.

Comment: ok thanks ill trry it!